# Can you loop input() to store multiple variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

e.g
I want to the user to assign numbers to 3 variables

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
```

I know you can do it like this;

```
a,b,c = input()
>>>1,2,3
```

but I need it to be asked on separate lines like the first example.

Is there a way to do something like this;

```
a,b,c = input() for range(3)
```

Comment: Store them in a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
a,b,c = (input() for _ in range(3))
```

repl.it link:
http://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/input-comprehension (Thanks to @Harun Yimaz in the comments below)

Comment: Here's a working repl.it: https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/input-comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splattering your global scope, use a dict instead:

```
dct = {key: input() for key in ["a", "b", "c"]}
print(dct)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to programming, can you expand on what you mean by "splattering your global scope"? 

Do you just mean don't waste/ use unnecessary global scope variables ?

Comment: @jackwquinton: Yes, exactly.